# Routine to convert decimal digits to Densely Packed Decimal

Tags: performance, bitwise, assembly, amd64

I've written an amd64 assembly routine (in gas syntax using the System V calling convention) to convert three decimal digits to [Densely packed decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Densely_packed_decimal) because I wasn't satisfied by the performance of the assembly generated by gcc and clang for all implementations of the conversion I could think of. Here is the code:

```
    .section .text
    .type decimal2dpd,@function
    .globl decimal2dpd

    # convert three digits abc to DPD
    # SysV calling convention: a in edi, b in esi, c in edx
    # assumes 0 <= a, b, c < 10
    .align 8
decimal2dpd:
    mov %esi,%eax
    shl $4,%eax
    or %edx,%eax
    and $0021,%eax
    shl $7,%edi
    or %edi,%eax
    and $016,%edx
    btr $10,%eax

    # at this point, eax = (a & 7) << 4 | (b & 1) << 4 | (c & 1) and CF is set if a > 7
    # and edi is free for use
    jc .Lagt7

    # here a < 8
    shl $4,%esi
    btr $7,%esi
    jc .Lbgt7

    # here a < 8 and b < 8
    or %esi,%eax
    or %edx,%eax
    ret

    .align 8
.Lbgt7: # here a < 8 and b > 7
    or $0012,%eax
    shl $4,%edx
    mov $0104,%edi
    btr $7,%edx
    cmovc %edi,%edx
    or %edx,%eax
    ret

    .align 8
.Lagt7: # here a > 7
    shl $7,%edx # eax = (a & 1 | c & 6) << 7 | (b & 1) << 5 | (c & 1)
    or %edx,%eax    # now eax[10] is set if c > 7
    btr $10,%eax
    jc .Lcgt7

    # here a > 7 and c < 8
    or $0014,%eax
    shl $4,%esi
    mov $0002,%edi
    btr $7,%esi
    cmovc %edi,%esi
    or %esi,%eax
    ret

    .align 8
.Lcgt7: # here a > 7 and c > 7
    and $016,%esi
    or $0056,%eax
    shl $7,%esi
    mov $0100,%edi
    btr $10,%esi
    cmovc %edi,%esi
    or %esi,%eax
    ret
    .size decimal2dpd,.-decimal2dpd
```

This routine is roughly 10% faster than the C code implementing roughly the same algorithm shown below. I would like to know if there is any obvious or less obvious way to improve this routine for better performance.

```
extern unsigned
decimal2dpd(unsigned a, unsigned b, unsigned c)
{
    unsigned result = c & 1 | (a & 7) << 7;

    if (a < 8) {
        if (b < 8)
            return result | b << 4 | c;
        else
            return result | (c > 7 ? 0104 : (c & 6) << 4) | (b & 1) << 4 | 0012;
    } else {
        result |= (b & 1) << 4;

        if (c < 8)
            return result | (c & 6) << 7 | (b > 7 ? 0002 : b << 4) | 0014;
        else
            return result | (b > 7 ? 0100 : (b & 6) << 7) | 0056;
    }
}
```

I especially believe that the fact that all arguments are in the range 0–9 can be exploited further, I didn't found a way to do so though (except for `a`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a tiny (24 byte) lookup table and some multiplication trickery, I was able to make the following implementation (roughly 1.5 times as fast as the original):

```
        .section .text
        .type bcd2dpd_mul,@function
        .globl bcd2dpd_mul

        # convert BCD to DPD with multiplication tricks
        # input abcd efgh iklm in edi
        .align 8
bcd2dpd_mul:
        mov %edi,%eax           #   = 0000 abcd efgh iklm
        shl %al                 #   = 0000 abcd fghi klm0
        shr %eax                #   = 0000 0abc dfgh iklm
        test $0x880,%edi        # fast path for a = e = 0
        jz 1f

        and $0x888,%edi         #   = 0000 a000 e000 i000
        imul $0x0490,%di        #   = aei0 0000 0000 0000
        mov %eax,%esi
        and $0x66,%esi          # q = 0000 0000 0fg0 0kl0
        shr $13,%edi            # u = 0000 0000 0000 0aei
        imul tab-8(,%rdi,4),%si # v = q * tab[u-2][0]
        and $0x397,%eax         # r = 0000 00bc d00h 0klm
        xor %esi,%eax           # w = r ^ v
        or tab-6(,%rdi,4),%ax   # x = w | tab[u-2][1]
        and $0x3ff,%eax         #   = 0000 00xx xxxx xxxx
1:      ret

        .size bcd2dpd_mul,.-bcd2dpd_mul

        .section .rodata
        .align 4
tab:
        .short 0x0011 ; .short 0x000a
        .short 0x0000 ; .short 0x004e
        .short 0x0081 ; .short 0x000c
        .short 0x0008 ; .short 0x002e
        .short 0x0081 ; .short 0x000e
        .short 0x0000 ; .short 0x006e
        .size tab,.-tab
```

which was optimized further with help from the folks on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34111959/417501).